# CurrentItem vs Hyperlink

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, navigation

I have a situtation. Im creating Listbox in Silverlight Navigation App and as datatemplate i have Grid with HyperlinkButton.

I need to select ListBox.CurrentItem **AND** to Navigate by HyperlinkButton the same time.

Problem is that it only navigates but not selects item.

P.S. Im using MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, you should be able to pass the `DataContext` of the `HyperlinkButton` to it's command via `CommandParameter={Binding }`. You then should be able to set whatever property on your viewmodel that is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the listbox.

Something Like

```
<HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxName, Path=DataContext.linkClickedCommand}" CommandParameter={Binding }/>

private void ExeucteLinkClickedCommand(object parameter)
{
    this.SelectedItem = (ItemType)parameter;
}
```